# preg_grep EXIF tag pattern from network dump (textfile)

Tags: php, exif

Looking for help in extracting EXIF GPS tags from a network dump text file.
I know the dump has the EXIF GPS tags of data in there, i just can't scrape it out with preg_grep

currently trying:

```
$data = file('networkdump.txt');

$matches = preg_grep("/EXIF/", $data);

echo $matches;
```

Getting currently:

```
Array
```

Looking for:

```
<exif:GPSTimeStamp>2013-02-19T04:39:05Z</exif:GPSTimeStamp>
<exif:GPSAltitude>33/1</exif:GPSAltitude>
```

Obviously without the tags, so i cant print them accordingly

Look forward to hearing your responses

Comment: Well... what happens when you do ``var_dump($matches);``? preg_grep doesn't return a string of text, it returns an array of matches. And if you try to echo an array, it'll print ``Array``, just like you get.

Comment: @JoelHinz, How would I go about removing the tags leaving just the faw data....?

Comment: I guess you could just remove anything inside <>.